# fan transmitter

Tags: fans, remote-control

I went to a realitives home who has a cealing fan installed  . I noticed the cealing fan has a set up of what I’m trying to accomplish,   with remote and power is controlling a lap in the room .I opened up the switch plate and noticed
The wiring is three sets of wiring:
All blk capped
All white capped
All grounding capped
And remote cealing fan mounted next to switch
The only difference is this cealing fan has the reviver and remote transmitter  option to be able to select different frequencies to communicate with remote and the transmitter  ??
When I remove the cover to the  access thr batteries and on the fan recicer I can see the option to mix the  numbers as well?
On The cealing fan I’m trying to connect dose not have these the option to select different frequency on the remote and transmitter?
I went home and connected all the wires the same but the fan did not work ?  Dose anyone have any suggestions? I’m thinking to re- purchase a fan that has the option to select the number frequency option  and seen if that has anything  to do with why the fan is not getting power. Thank you anyone Ed Beal if you have any suggestions

Comment: Can you please edit the photo you originally posted in this question into the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

You have labeled showing 2wht, 3wht, 3 ground, 2 black, pig tail and black.
The connections appear to have the proper size wire nuts. It appears to be lacking a cover plate for the switch that also has a red. What other advice would you like?